# How do I create a live video stream with a Raspberry Pi and a Java tomcat server?

Tags: python, camera, java

I'm trying to live stream video from a Raspberry Pi to webpages of the connected clients, for example: the server will be hosted in one location "A" and the Raspberry Pi is connected to this server. If a user accesses the web application from location "B" using the URL, and wants to view the live video, how can I achieve this?

As per my understanding I have to stream content from Raspberry Pi webcam to a Tomcat server. Please suggest to me how can I achieve this. Please do suggest me some examples as well.

Answer (score 1):

`uv4l` is pretty good for streaming with very little lag

http://www.linux-projects.org/uv4l/

```
$ curl http://www.linux-projects.org/listing/uv4l_repo/lrkey.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

then add the source to your source list `sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list`

```
$ source="deb http://www.linux-projects.org/listing/uv4l_repo/raspbian/ jessie main" 
$ echo $source | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

then `update`, and get the packages you need

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install uv4l uv4l-raspicam uv4l-raspicam-extras uv4l-server uv4l-webrtc
```

update your firmware

```
$ sudo rpi-update
```

the run the server

```
$ uv4l --driver raspicam --auto-video_nr --width 640 --height 480 --encoding h264
```

go to http://raspberrypi:8080/stream in a browser on the network to view the stream (where raspberrypi is your pi's ip or hostname)

```
$ sudo pkill uv4l
```

to stop it

Answer (score 0):

I would start with this [stream m](https://github.com/vbence/stream-m) you can set it up on your server. Then on  raspberry pi you could use ffmpeg to stream h264 or webm video from your raspberry camera.